# What happens when nginx worker connections (or max requests?) have exhausted?

Tags: nginx, webserver

Assuming worker_process is 4

And worker_connections is 500

This means there are 2000 max concurrent connections allowed.

1. Does this mean 2000 is the max number of connections or max number of requests?
2. What happens when the 2001th connection or request arrives? Will it be rejected or be added to queue?

Answer (score 1):

1. It is max number of connections
2. It will be rejected. There is no queue mechanism in nginx.

Comment: Within 1 connection does it have any limit of number of requests that it can handle in parallel?

Comment: Well on 1 connection you can only handle 1 request at a time.
So if you want n requests to be processed in parallel you will need n concurrent connections.